# Como fazer um sistema em web rodar em um dispositivo móvel com o IIS 7?

Tags: php, css, asp.net

Meu grupo de tcc está  desenvolvendo um sistema em ASP.net e CSS, em que existe um servidor conectado á um roteador sem fio onde o sistema sera acessado por tablets conectados á essa rede, estou realizando testes com o IIS mas nao esta dando certo.Minha duvida é como eu posso acessar um programa em um dispositivo móvel conectado à rede local?

Grato

Comment: Eu não entendi o PHP nas tags. A resposta pratica, seria: Abra o browser do celular, digite o ip e porta HTTP (por exemplo: `http://10.0.0.123:8000`) da maquina com o servidor e a mágica acontece :)

Comment: Se for usar como um sistema local os tablets devem estar na mesma rede do servidor IIS.